How to manage the throwing exception in the afterReadEvent
I'm using the FileHelpers library, version 3.1.5 from NuGet and am running into a problem while trying to use the AfterReadRecord event. When I throw an exception from this event, it's my understanding that the library will catch exceptions from AfterReadRecord event and build the ErrorInfo collection from them. The FileHelpers is buliding the Errors collection, however the unhandled exception is leaving the application in fault state mode.
I am getting this warning:

"Exception was unhandled by user code" warning in VS2019. "An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in FileHelpersTest.exe but was not handled in user code" "Additional information: field1 is invalid".

My code:
public void AfterRead(AfterReadEventArgs e)
{
    if (AccountName != null && AccountName.Contains("340B"))
    {
         e.SkipThisRecord = true;
         throw new FileHelpersException("Account name is not accepted");
    }
}

// this is throwing Unhandled exception causing the application into Fault state mode

